# How to remove old single-hole kitchen faucet

Tags: plumbing

I'm replacing my old kitchen faucet. Disconnecting the supply lines is no problem, but then I get stuck loosening the faucet from the deck. The lines go through a metal C-shaped washer-like thing, and I'm not sure what's holding it fast. I'm also not sure what to do with the gray plastic piece between the C-shaped piece and the sink.

Photos:

[image: underside of sink]

[image: from other side]

Comment: It looks like you could put a wrench on the end of that brass pipe - does it unscrew?

Comment: Do you know what brand faucet it is? Is it possible that the copper looking piece with the threads holds the u shaped clip in place? What does the faucet look like from above?  Could the plastic nuts to each side of the middle hole, hold the faucet down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some interaction between the center threaded rod with the slot in it and the outer tube is what holds "C" clamp in place. I would try holding the center rod with a large flat blade screwdriver in the slot and loosening the tube with pliers by turning the rod CCW. If that doesn't work, then try turning the rod CW and see if this releases the outer tube.

The outer plastic nuts just unscrew.

Comment: Turned out the outer tube could be loosened with a wrench; no need to hold the threaded rod. Unscrewed it all the way down, then the C-clamp came off and so did the gray plastic triangle (though it was slightly stuck to the underside of the deck). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; I ended up cutting through the faucet, from the top, as close to the sink itself as possible.  You have to be careful not to damage the sink, but it only took about ten minutes to do, versus several hours of trying to do it properly.

Comment: I haven't tried one of these, but I have trouble thinking it would take several hours "to do it properly".

Comment: Sorry, bad phrasing.  I'd spent several hours trying to do it properly; it was a pedestal sink, and there wasn't really room to maneuver.  I've since learned that the preferred approach is to disassemble the sink, so you have room to work.  Still, in the case where you aren't planning to reuse the old faucet, it works well.  An oscillating cutter made short work of it.

Comment: What kind of blade did you use on the oscillating cutter to cut the tube (brass?) and the threaded rod (also brass?)? How close to the sink did you cut? Did you unscrew the outer two plastic nuts or did you cut them too?

Comment: I used Bosch OSL114C-3 Starlock Carbide Plunge Cut Blade; that cut through everything.  I cut as close to the sink as I could; I did slightly scratch the sink, but the replacement faucet covered the scratch.  Once I'd cut through the top of the faucet, the bottom just fell down; I didn't have to worry about anything underneath the sink.  The top of the faucet is being held on by the chrome and everything surrounding the faucet, so when you cut through it and remove the top of the faucet, there's nothing holding it in place anymore.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that the cutting was done on the top; I assumed (incorrectly) that the cutting was done on the underside.